# Go package imports self, and can't find itself in it the GOPATH

Tags: go

Every once in awhile, I'll use a go package that has a go get like : `go get github.com/<user>/aRepo` and in its own import statement have `import "github.com/<user>/aRepo"`. So it imports itself using a the "go gettable" path.  Sometimes this works fine; however, sometimes I get

```
package github.com/<user>/aRepo
imports github.com/<user>/aRepo
imports github.com/<user>/aRepo: cannot find package "github.com/<user>/aRepo" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/<user>/aRepo (from $GOROOT)
/home/me/go/src/github.com/<user>/aRepo (from $GOPATH)
```

I set my GOPATH with:

```
export GOPATH=$GOPATH:/home/me/go:`godep path`
```

It's very unclear as to why this would happen, any ideas as to why?

EDIT

my `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=":/home/vagrant/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out it was a permissions issue since I was using a vagrant box with a synced folder, vagrant set the entire path that synced folder created as 744 root:root.  Therefore, I could not write to that folder as a non-root user, so that error message is actually coming from godep trying to install itself and not finding its src.